# primitive vector deletion throws exception

Tags: c++, vector

the problem is the title, when debugging right before the delete instruction i can see that the pointer(vector) is fine, i can even modify its values through the VC++Express2013 immediate window, but after the delete it throw the exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x55ACDF62 (msvcp120d.dll) in BTREE.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xABABABAB.
```

My vector is a vector of this class:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class Pair{
public:
Pair(){
    key = Key();
    value = Value();
}

Pair(Key key, Value value){
    this->key = key;
    this->value = value;
}

Key key;
Value value;
};
```

in the templates i use int for the key and std::string for the value, the vector is only allocated via this method:

```
Node(unsigned int max){
    nelements = 0;
    nchilds = 0;
    /*reserva espaço para os elementos e os nós filhos, cada vetor possui uma espaço adicional reservado*/
    elements = new Pair<Key, Value>[max];
    childs = new Node<Key, Value>*[max + 1];
    this->max = max;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++)
        childs[i] = nullptr;
}
```

more complicated operations using this vector are here:

```
        left->nelements = middle;
    memcpy(left->elements, elements, sizeof(Pair<Key, Value>) * middle);
    if (!leaf()){
        left->nchilds = middle + 1;
        memcpy(left->childs, childs, sizeof(Node<Key, Value>*) * left->nchilds);
    }
```

and here is the destructor:

```
~Node(){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nchilds; i++)
            delete childs[i];
    delete[] childs;
    delete[] elements;
}
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: DId you try to eliminate one thing at time? You can start with constructing the vector and deleting it afterwards. Add more code until error shows up.

Comment: If the real types used for either `Key` or `Value` are non-trivial, the use of `memcpy` is invalid and the result undefined. You might want to use `std::copy` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says your code (or rather CRT) tried to write at memory location with value 0xABABABAB. Under debugger Visual Studio sets this value to help find bugs. It means:

```
Used by HeapAlloc() to mark "no man's land" guard bytes after allocated heap memory
```

Because this exception originates from `delete` it means that either you have corrupted heap by overwriting some memory buffers, or you are trying to delete dangling pointer.

One thing that looks suspicious is that you are using memcpy to copy `elements` - you should memcpy only trivial types. To check if that is a case use static assertion:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Pair<Key, Value>>::value, "must be TriviallyCopyable type");
```

Its always better to use `std::copy` - it will use `memmove` for TriviallyCopyable types, and otherwise will copy elements one by one.

To prevent from having such bugs, you should use `std::vector` instead of dynamic arrays, if you need pointers then you might use `std::unique_ptr`. Combined with various functions from `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: thanks for helping, changing the memcpy with std::copy really worked, thanks for the tips too.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you copy the allocated memory.

```
 memcpy(left->elements, elements, sizeof(Pair<Key, Value>) * middle);
    if (!leaf()){
        left->nchilds = middle + 1;
        memcpy(left->childs, childs, sizeof(Node<Key, Value>*) * left->nchilds);
    }
```

From a `Node` instance to another?

In this case, are you sure that you free an allocated pointer only one time?